Identify this Indian comedy movie about foolish young men
I believe in the beginning of the movie, some young men hear a woman scream in a bus driving in the street. They automatically think she has been kidnapped and chase after the bus to rescue her. they finally caught up with the driver and start beating him. Then they realize that he is only trying to rush his pregnant wife who is in labour to the hospital.
I think there were 3 young men and were often regarded as jobless, could not pay their rent or were squatting in someone else's apartment. 
It think it was released between 2009-2013

There are many languages in Indian cinema. Which language was it? Do you remember any famous actors? Who was heroine in it? Please add more details. Do you remember any dialogue or song from it?

I believe the movie you are talking about is 'Dhol' by Priyadarshan. It begins with the same opening scene described by you but it was released in 2007 and is a story of 4 goofy jobless friends.
Youtube - Dhol (2007) Hindi Movie w/Eng Subs 
IMDb - Dhol (2007)

Oh my gosh! Thanks so much. I've been looking for this movie since 2012! I only watched up to the scene I described because of a power outage. I can finally finish it.

@Okumen happy to help
